# Windows universal app Rest API Raspberry Pi

Tags: windows, raspberry-pi2, iot

I have Windows Core running on a Raspberry PI. How do I create a rest API in a Windows universal app to run on it?  I want to be able send remote commands to the Raspberry PI from a mobile device. I did several search and couldn't find much information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As noted [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/32380/windows-10-iot-on-rpi2-as-a-small-http-rest-web-api-server) there's a [Restup](https://github.com/tomkuijsten/restup) open source project for this

and [NuGet package for it](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Restup/)

There's also some experimental (ie fun side project) from Damian on the ASP.NET team about hosting DNX (the host process for your ASP.NET Core apps) located [here](https://github.com/DamianEdwards/PiDnx) but that will need some updating to the latest bits.