# Is it possible totransform my windows iot app into a dll?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, raspberry-pi, windows-iot-core-10

I am new to windows iot core, Actually I am running it with a raspberry Pi3 
What I want to do is to create a .dll from an app based on windows iot core and integrate it in an other solution (WPF plateform) and whenever I call the .dll methods I get datas from my solution to my raspberry pi and vice versa

Actually I am confused about it there's not enough documentation about this and I don't know if this is possible or not if yes I would be very thankfull if you provide me some links

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you wish to use this "dll" to also communicate with your pi? Sounds more like a case for an API: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34908372/windows-universal-app-rest-api-raspberry-pi  https://jeremylindsayni.wordpress.com/2017/04/22/hosting-a-net-core-2-web-api-instance-on-the-raspberry-pi-3/

Comment: @LocEngineer yes I wanna communicate with my raspberry through this .dll but couldn't find something usefull till now !

Comment: Better to create an API then, that exposes your app's methods. You want to communicate cross-machine after all. I am not exactly proficient in PI programming but if you stop looking for "how to use dll for this" and more like "how to create API on Raspberry and interact", you might have a better chance at this.

Comment: @souihernajah What's kind of data do you want to transmit and what's device/platform do you communicate with raspberry pi?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT robot datas but these datas will be sent as a string ; Actually I have a wpf desktop app which is related to a robot I wanna integrate a dll in this app to sent robot datas to my raspberry which runs windows 10 iot core looks a little bit confusing but this is what they want me do

Comment: @souihernajah Ok. What's connection can be established between the robot and raspberry pi, network, bluetooth or hardware connection like UART, SPI etc?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT well we can establish a wifi connexion or ethernet ; I mean local network

Comment: @souihernajah Why do you want to transform your windows iot app into a dll? You want to use the same code that running on Windows IoT Core in WPF? Is your windows iot app a UWP application?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT yes my iot app is a UWP actually we want to add this dll to all our wpf solutions to avoid redondance I am wondering if this is possible !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I assume your WPF application running on Windows 10 device.

To use UWP API in WPF application you need Package your WPF applications ([Desktop Bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root)).

> When you create a package for your desktop application, your
>   application will get an identity and with that identity, your desktop
>   application has access to Windows Universal Platform (UWP) APIs.

[Package a desktop application by using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net)

[Using a UWP C++ dll in Win32 C# WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786164/using-a-uwp-c-dll-in-win32-c-sharp-wpf-application)

- If your WPF application running on lower version than Windows 10 you can't use above solution.

In this case you need implement network send and receive logic respectively for WPF and UWP. Establish, for example, socket connection between them.